# Hazelcast partition queue

Tags: hazelcast

Is there a way to see the size of partition queue in hazelcast? 
Context:
We are using 1399 partitions in our hazelcast cluster and all the IMap updates are being done through entryprocessors. Some of these updates take a large time on an average(as observed from client side). Is there a way to look into the hazelcast partition queue size maintained for each partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [Diagnostic Logs](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#diagnostics) to get detailed information related to the partition operation threads. Also, you can use [Health Monitoring](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/manual/html-single/#health-monitor) to see total pending invocation counts.